# How to find out Altair default title font type and font size?

Tags: altair, vega-lite, vega

I am currently working on a Streamlit application. I use mainly Plotly and Altair for my plots. I would like to use the Altair default font type and font size for my Plotly chart titles. How can I find out the title font type and font size set as default on my Altair plots? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Just a note that  I updated my answer with a link to the vega file that I believe holds the default settings.

Answer (score 0):

The charts from Altair are rendered using the JS library Vega. I believe Vega just specified whether the font should be serif, sans-serif, monospace, etc and then uses the default font in your browser for this font category. [This comment from a Vega maintainer](https://github.com/vega/vega/issues/2215#issuecomment-560326533) seems to suggest so as well.

There is also a [vega-themes package](https://github.com/vega/vega-themes) that defines overrides to the default theme via CSS.

[For font-sizes, I believe the default are what is listed in this file](https://github.com/vega/vega/blob/7eafbbd4d53d0ce9f08e74ff96c90d411b1bb80a/packages/vega-parser/src/config.js#L82-L129)